Only show rows with values in Power BI
EDIT: The solution below worked because the DAX was checking the "First" value out of multiple items in each group, which may be null even though another row in the group has a value. By looking at the MAX value, it can be determined if there is any value among all items in the group.
I am using this DAX to determine if a row is empty in a matrix. The results are inconsistent however. I'm checking for length and ISBLANK. What is a more effective what to determine if a row is empty?
ShowRow = 
IF(
    (ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curHrs])) || LEN(TRIM(SELECTEDVALUE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curHrs]))) = 0) &&
    (ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curAmt])) || LEN(TRIM(SELECTEDVALUE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curAmt]))) = 0) &&
    (ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_Comments2])) || LEN(TRIM(SELECTEDVALUE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_Comments2]))) = 0)
,
"Empty",
"NOT Empty"
)



maybe you can try this
ShowRow = 
IF(
    (ISBLANK(MAX(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curHrs])) || LEN(TRIM(MAX(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curHrs]))) = 0) &&
    (ISBLANK(MAX(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curAmt])) || LEN(TRIM(MAX(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curAmt]))) = 0) &&
    (ISBLANK(MAX(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_Comments2])) || LEN(TRIM(MAX(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_Comments2]))) = 0)
,
"Empty",
"NOT Empty"
)


Simply try with COALESCE  to better handle cases where the values might be BLANK() or empty strings. If a value is blank, it returns an empty string "" for comparison.
ShowRow = 
IF(
    COALESCE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curHrs], "") = "" &&
    COALESCE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curAmt], "") = "" &&
    COALESCE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_Comments2], "") = ""
,
    "Empty",
    "NOT Empty"
)


Thank you Amira. This does not seem to have any effect on what is returned however. I get the same results. Incidentally, I have to include "SelectedValue" or I receive an error. So COALESCE(SELECTEDVALUE(VP2Fabric___Project_Progress[detail_curHrs]), "") = "" for instance.

Can you share some data and the desired output ?

Turns out its due to grouping - the first item in some cases are different than the summed amounts.

Can you provide data ?

Thank you Amira. The solution by Ryan worked by looking at the MAX for the given field.
